# What when @Asynchronous method calls another @Asynchronous method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb, websphere

So the title says it all, what happens when during asynchronous invocation of a method performed by Java EE Container, there is a call to another method that is also annotated with @Asynchronous. I would expect that there will be one more asynchronous invocation. However the specification does not say anything about this, so could this also be Application sever vendor specific?

Currently I am analyzing the performance of a Java EE application that runs in Websphere. And I clearly see within the method tree that the second asynchronous method will actually be synchronously called. This actually makes sense for me, because we are already in some kind of asynchronous context, so instead of submitting new task we can just execute it right away..

Any idea about this?

Comment: The second asynchronous method should be asynchronous to the first.  Can you show the stack trace where the second method is being called synchronously?  That would be a product defect.

Comment: Problem is that the application I am analyzing is from one of our customers, so I can not post any stack traces or similar application sensitive stuff..

Comment: Can you replace their classes/methods (like com.example.Xyz.method1)?

Comment: Is the second method on the same SB as the first?

Answer (score 0):

This works. The second call will just post a request to execute that method to some internal queue that the AS maintains.

BUT... be very careful with waiting on the results from any Future that the second method might return. If the second method is a void method it's always safe.